# Ubuntu configure the package not found text

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Is it possible to configure the response from the apt-get system for when a user attempts to install a package on an offline system or when they are not allowed to display custom text to the user?

e.g.: The `Command <package-name> was not found` could become custom text provided to apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

"configure"? Not really, but you could create a wrapper script that harvested the response and fed it into `apt`.

I would be wary of this approach, though -- a malicious actor could use this feature to install something you didn't want installed.  If somehow `/tmp/bad-juju.deb` gets forced into `apt install /tmp/bad-juju.deb` for instance...

Not all `<command>` possibilities are mapped directly to `<package-name>`.  Example: `zcat` is part of `gzip`.  `apt install zcat` doesn't work.

I would suggest if I may be so bold, that the correct approach would be to create images that have all required packages, and deploy those.